# Can inner classes be excluded from sonar code duplication

Tags: sonarqube, inner-classes, code-duplication

In our application there are inner classes defined to create and destroy local variables.
But I want to exclude these inner classes from sonar code duplication violations as all inner classes will have same kind of blocks it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. This is real code duplication, which means you should be able to refactor this into a single place.